# WPF Window SizeToContent grows beyond desktop size

Tags: wpf, multiple-monitors, sizetocontent

WPF `Window` `SizeToContent` grows beyond desktop size. I guess this could be caused because of my multiple-monitor setup. How should I restrict `Window` to grow only to size of active `Window` (no more than maximized)?

Comment: Well you could listen to sizechanged and modify accordingly. Or you could just set the root content element to the desired maxsize. Or, thats my advise, don't use SizeToContent at all :)

Comment: I can not go with static size, because window has dynamic content (content window). Actually what I need I somehow to get active desktop work area, I guess? Although I played with setting maxWidth and this change cause inner controls to act very wierd.

Comment: max width doesn't work? maybe you should add a `ScrollView` like `Window`-> `Scrollview`-> `content`

Comment: ScrollView just makes things worse. It would still grow a lot, because window does not know that it is limited to active window + ScrollViewer would mess up "*" collumns/rows for underlaying controls. What I really need is to tell that window - dont grow bigger than current screen. Problem is - how to get current screen size. Can use some functionality from winforms, but that only returns screen size, but does not account for things like taskbar.

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF can't you add `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` on the inner scroll viewer? -- So that it grows, but only to a point?